# HTML Object element and scrollbar issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using the following HTML to embed HTML from an external URL into my site and it works great:

```
<object data="https://myapp.com/explore" width="100%" height="100%" type="text/html" style="overflow: hidden;">
    <embed src="https://myapp.com/explore" width="100%" height="100%;" /> 
    Error: Embedded data could not be displayed.
</object>
```

On the page, a vertical scroll bar is shown, which is the correct behavior I expect, as content is larger than the height of the Chrome browser window.

However, when I click the vertical scroll bar for the first time, the page scrolls... After that, without clicking, the page scrolls whenever the mouse is over the vertical scroll bar, WITHOUT me actually clicking to scroll.

Has anyone seen this, and can you suggest how to solve?  It's a weird behavior I have not seen before...

Comment: to clarify, when i click on the scroll bar..it seems to never release, and remain stuck in pressed/stick mode.

Comment: Question, do you even want a scroll feature?

Comment: 1.that's most probably a browser bug, 
2.if the browser supports object tag api, it shouldn't show scrollbars at all.
3.if it does but still shows a scroll, the scroll bar belongs to the embedded browser element whose mouse up sequence is being lost during the scroll.

Comment: The bug has been reported several times in the Chromium tracker but no solution has been proposed, apparently. See issues [305335](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=305335), [406611](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=406611), and [601377](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=601377).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried your object + embed approach, and encountered the same problem with the scrollbar. The Chrome browser seems to not trigger the `mousedown` on the scrollbar, but does fire the `mouseup`, which looks like a bug. Why not try an iframe? It works as you expect, I think:

```
<iframe id="exploreIFrame" src="http://myapp.com/explore"
  width="100%" height="100%" style="border: none;"
></iframe>
```

To make it span the entire window, set these styles:

```
<style type="text/css">
  body { margin: 0; }
  #exploreIFrame { position: fixed; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `max-height` property in pixels, and use the `overflow` property to scroll...

```
 object_classname{
     max-height: 600px; //as you like
     overflow-y: scroll;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to use an iframe instead of an embed.

**iframe:**

The iframe element represents a nested browsing context. The HTML 5 Standard describes "The  element" as primarily used to include resources from other domains or subdomains, but can be used to include content from the same domain as well. The iframe's strength is that the embedded code is 'live' and can communicate with the parent document.

**embed:**

Standardized in HTML 5, but before that, it was a non standard tag, which admittedly, was implemented by all major browsers. Behavior prior to HTML 5 can vary...

The embed element provides an integration point for an external (typically non-HTML) application or interactive content. The HTML 5 Standard describes "The  element" as used to embed content for browser plugins. Exceptions to this are SVG and HTML, which are handled differently according to the standard.

The details of what can and cannot be done with the embedded content is up to the browser plugin in question. But for SVG, you can access the embedded SVG document from the parent with something like:

```
svg = document.getElementById("parent_id").getSVGDocument();
```

From inside an embedded SVG or HTML document, you can reach the parent with:

```
parent = window.parent.document;
```

For embedded HTML, there is no way to get at the embedded document from the parent (that I have found).

Comment: This answer would have been better if 1) it actually addressed the OP's quesrtion, and 2) if the OP hadn't been using <object>. HTML pages in objects can target the parent document just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Couldbe hardware related. If you have a button/wheel on the mouse that you are clicking when you select the scrollbar. IT sounds like a problemI experienced with amouse that had an extra button on a scroll wheel.